# Help troubleshooting PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I've just started learning aboud PDO and prepared statements (which sure seem to beat remembering to use mysql_real_escape_string() every time) but I'm having trouble getting the script to execute properly:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "start";

try{
    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME','USER','PWD');
} 
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error connecting to MySQL!: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid= ?');
$dbh->execute(array('15400743'));
$result=$dbh->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
echo "end";
?>
```

This is pretty much copied from example code, but when executed only returns "start". I've double-checked my db/user/pw. Anything else people see wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to set `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`. Otherwise you have to check the return value of each called method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "start";

try{
    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME','USER','PWD');
} 
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error connecting to MySQL!: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid= ?');
$stmt->execute(array('15400743'));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
echo "end";
?>
```

Note the assinment of the prepare to the $stmt variable and the use of that afterwards.